# toolchain and libraries

Tags: compilation, toolchain, uclibc, newlib

When we compile a toolchain, we need to specify which library we are using to compile the toolchain. For example, i recently compiled toolchain for openRISC architecture. They gave me an option to choose from uClibc and newlib.

Is it necessary to compile a toolchain with a library? While working on say embedded linux, cant i just compile a library on the target platform, and the use the toolchain (compiled without the library) and link the library with the user program ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

well , yes we have to specify the c library in order to build a toolchain . Like uClibc is mainly for micro controller ( later for processors ) , musl libc is for less than 32MB of size ( for smaller memory ) , glibc is for large memory but not very configurable . glibc is for wildly ( POSIX compatible). Also you have take care of other supporting libraries while building toolchain ( whether POSIX compatibility) etc.

Answer (score -1):

Of coarse it is necessary to compile a toolchain with a library. In order to lessen the search and become more convenient. Everybody wants everything so quickly nowadays if they dont get it straight away they get annoyed but we should learn how to become useful and productive sometimes. Libraries and toolchain are very important.